GroupingBy with multiple filters and using filtername as key in the outputmap
Say I have 3 or n filters. Say 3 for the sake of it.
Say I define these filters and create a map of it as well
class Person {
      Strong status;
}

Predicate<Person> completedP = j->j.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("completed");
Predicate<Person> inProgressP = j->j.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("inprogress");
Predicate<Person> nullStatusP = j->j.getStatus() == null && j.id() == null;

Map<String, Predicate<Person>> filterMap =  Map.of("complatedP",completedP, 
"inProgressP", inProgressP, "nullStatusP", nullStatusP);


Now say I have an input as List<Person> people
How do I get the output/result as
Map<String, List<Person>>
Consider the following sample data
        Person p1 = new Person("completedP");
        Person p2 = new Person("completedP");
                
        Person p3 = new Person("inProgressP");
        Person p4 = new Person("inProgressP");
        
        Person p5 = new Person(null);
        Person p6 = new Person(null);

I want the result as:
completedP key to have p1,p2
inProgressP key to have p3,p4
nullStatusP key to have p5,p6
The key to the result map is one of the 3 filter names. I do not want to do
groupBy 3 times and apply single filter each time.
How do I generalize if it I have a N filters in the map. For my current requirement, 3 filters is all I need though

I am assuming that when you say you do not want to groupBy 3 times, that means no streaming/iterating over the list/map of predicates and filtering the input based on the "current" predicate?

I have added an example. I also meant I do not want to iterate multiple times for each filter

You can write a helper method that tells you the key to group by, given the Map of filters and a Person.
private static String group(Map<String, Predicate<Person>> filters, Person person) {
    return filters.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getValue().test(person))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findAny().orElseThrow();
}

This assumes that every Person matches exactly one filter, and will throw an exception if a Person does not match any filters. You can change orElseThrow to orElse("some other group") to put those in another group.
Then you can do:
var groups = people.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> group(filterMap, x)));


Thank you. why use findAny vs findFirst?

@BIBOOunit in above answer, how do I add a default filter?

@curiousengineer of course findFirst works too, but I think findAny also expresses the idea that the order isn't important. These do perform differently for parallel streams, but here it's just a stylistic choice.

a bit hard to explain if the previous comment didnt help. Let me show you.

@BIBOOunit In the best case scenario, every person matches the first filter. In the worst case scenario, every person is matched against all the filters, so its O(NumPeople * NumFilters). I'm pretty sure it is impossible to get a better worst case complexity than that.

thank you both, a lot. You people are great

@Sweeper one Q about group function. I understand you call map in it because I want to return the string and you are transforming the Map.Entry to get the string(key). But findAny function can be before map as well right?  I mean the order between map and findAny won't matter correct?

@curiousengineer Yeah you can totally do that. The overall behaviour doesn't change. Do note that if you put map after findAny then you'd be calling Optional.map, which is a different method from Stream.map.

@OP, this is what I meant by having a default filter that will return true for everything. Though, in this case the order of the mapping will matter (LinkedHashMap will be needed)
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sample data
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList("apple", "banana", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "frog");

        Map<String, Predicate<String>> map = Map.of("A",s -> s.startsWith("a"),
                                                    "B", s -> s.startsWith("b"),
                                                    "C", s -> s.startsWith("c"),
                                                    "D", s -> s.startsWith("d"),
                                                    "ANY", s -> true );

        // Grouping the data based on predicates
        Map<String, List<String>> groupedData = data.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> map.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(m -> m.getValue().test(str)).findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElseThrow()));

        for (var entry : groupedData.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

edit:
You can also use the .orElse() to provide the default string name instead of adding a new predicate to the map (in this case LinkedHashMap will not be needed)
Map<String, List<String>> groupedData = data.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> map.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(m -> m.getValue().test(str)).findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse("ANY")));

output:
A: [apple]
B: [banana]
C: [cat]
D: [dog]
ANY: [elephant, frog]

Also, if you are going to accept anything, don’t accept my answer, since I just basically referenced + modified @sweepers. Not really adding on anything

The iteration order of a map created by Map.of is unspecified. You'd need to use a LinkedHashMap or similar for the "any" case to work reliably.

Yeah, I m going to delete this answer later. Just made a quick modification to show what I meant.

Both, I am a bit greedy now. Last question on this. How do I ensure that filters are applied in a particular order? Because if I don't use a map, then I lose the way to attach a name to the filter that output map needs. I think you mean use LinkedHashMap for that reason as that is ordered(I know not sorted but ordered)

Well the linkedhash map is insertion order, so you can ensure that you insert your key value pairs in a specific order and the default will be last

don't delete it please

@curiousengineer Yes you'd use a LinkedHashMap like BIBOO unit said. You should also change findAny to findFirst. In practice findAny will probably behave the same as findFIrst for a non-parallel ordered stream, but findAny is still not guaranteed to return the first element, according to the documentation.
